# Android: swipe screen to open another activity?

Tags: android, gesture, swipe-gesture

i'm a n00b programmer and need a lot of help.

Just for tutorial purpose, I want to make simple flora & fauna (plant & animal) encyclopedia

I want to make my home screen **drag-able just like the Android's home screen**. Swipe right to open Plant page and swipe left to open Animal page.
I don't know how to make the **transition effect**. So we can drag it halfway to peek what's in next page and just drag back to cancel it

Can you guys share a link to make the drag-able screen?

Thanks before

**[Edit]**

@Agarwal
I tried the code from your Link2 and it's not working

I try to test whether the gesture detected or not by putting Toast inside the inner class but the Toast isn't shown. The Link1 is basically the same though.

and from the looks of the code, I think it can't make my screen drag-able like in Android's home screen

my code:

```
public class Home extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    ImageButton flora, fauna;
    Intent go;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initialize();

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
}

private void initialize() {
    //find view by id to image button
    //set onClickListener to image button
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //normal switch and case for each button

}

private void onLeftSwipe() {
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Left swipe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
    go = new Intent("test.apps.FLORA");
    startActivity(go);
}

private void onRightSwipe() {
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
    go = new Intent("test.apps.FAUNA");
    startActivity(go);
}

private class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Gesture detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
            float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
            float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

            if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;

            // Left swipe
            if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Home.this.onLeftSwipe();
            } 
            // Right swipe
            else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Home.this.onRightSwipe();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Home", "Error on gestures");
        }
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hey, quick question. Did you ever figure out why the link2 was not working? I am trying to get it to work as well. But am having no such luck right now.

Comment: Yes, I found a good source code for this dragable screen, here's the link http://marcreichelt.blogspot.sg/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html?m=1

Comment: @DarcCode link is broken, here's an alternative link [web.archive.org/web/2....](http://web.archive.org/web/20120728070120/http://marcreichelt.blogspot.sg/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html)

Comment: `GestureDetector` is now deprecated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I realise this is an old question but for anyone else wondering why the above code does not work it is because he has not set the OnTouchListener to a View object. This is why his swipe "event" is not being picked up, because nothing is listening for it.

He could add this line to set swipes on his image button (though you would probably want a better View object then this):

```
flora.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for bumping, found this via google. Trying to do something similar in my app. The more information the better.

Comment: I already found another alternative, but this answer would solve my question, Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

You should use ViewPager , please see the below links.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging

Comment: Thanks for adding more alternative solution. This will be useful for others

Answer (score 3):

**Android Activity Swipe Detection**

Create A Base Activity Class

```java
public abstract class _SwipeActivityClass extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector( this, new SwipeDetector());
    }

    protected abstract void onSwipeRight();
    protected abstract void onSwipeLeft();

    public class SwipeDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {

            // Check movement along the Y-axis. If it exceeds SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH,
            // then dismiss the swipe.
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //toast( "start = "+String.valueOf( e1.getX() )+" | end = "+String.valueOf( e2.getX() )  );
            //from left to right
            if( e2.getX() > e1.getX() )
            {
                if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
                {
                    onSwipeRight();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if( e1.getX() > e2.getX() )
            {
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
                {
                    onSwipeLeft();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        // TouchEvent dispatcher.
        if (gestureDetector != null)
        {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev))
            // If the gestureDetector handles the event, a swipe has been
            // executed and no more needs to be done.
            return true;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Then extend your **Activity** from **_SwipeActivityClass**

implement methods **onSwipeLeft()** and **onSwipeRight()** to start another activity

Comment: Hi @ManishDhruw, Thanks for the solution. It's working perfectly for me. I'm newbie to android. One more additional request is, Is it possible to change the activity slide directions bases on the swipe. I mean If I swipe left to right, activity loads from right to left(always). Can we change activity loading directions into left to right for left swipe and right to left for right swipe?

Comment: from what i understand your are looking for transition effect,

You need to store the preferred direction

startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));  
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in,R.anim.push_up_out);

I did not tested the code i copied it from [HERE](http://burnignorance.com/android-apps-development/animation-on-switching-between-activities/)